# Index out of bounds for length. Cant find error

Tags: java, arrays, indexing

I searched through other posts for someone having the same error which was similar to my code, but i could not find it. the current issue i am having is with my variables totalRate[] and years[]. I can not input a number greater than 6 into either arrayList, while my clientNames[] and amountInvested[] are working just fine. Can anyone spot my error?

```
public class Lab04_Part_1 {
  @SuppressWarnings("null")
public static void main(String[] args) {

      Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
      double search = 0;
      double [] [] table = {  {1.05, 1.06, 1.07, 1.08, 1.09, 1.10},//row 1
                {1.1025, 1.1236, 1.1449, 1.1664, 1.1881, 1.21}, //row 2
                {1.1576250, 1.1910160, 1.2250430, 1.2597120, 1.2950290, 1.331}, //row 3
                {1.2155063, 1.2624770, 1.3107960, 1.3604890, 1.4115816, 1.4641},//row 4
                {1.2762816, 1.3382256, 1.4025517, 1.4693281, 1.5386240, 1.61051}, //row 5
                {1.3400956, 1.4185191, 1.5007304, 1.5868743, 1.6771001, 1.771561}, //row 6
                {1.4071004, 1.5036303, 1.6057815, 1.7138243, 1.8280391, 1.9487171}, //row 7
                {1.4774554, 1.5938481, 1.7181862, 1.8509302, 1.9925626, 2.1435888}, //row 8
                {1.5513282, 1.6894790, 1.8384592, 1.9990046, 2.1718933, 2.3579477}, //row 9
                {1.6288946, 1.7908477, 1.9671514, 2.1589250, 2.3673637, 2.5937425} //row 10
    }; // end declaration and initialization of 2D array

    // Declare String [ ] and int array(s) here
      final int totalClients = 5;
      String [] clientNames = new String[totalClients];
      int [] totalRate = new int[totalClients];
      int [] years = new int[totalClients];
      int [] amountInvested = new int[totalClients];
    
    // Declare for loop used for input here
      for(int i = 0; i < totalClients; i++) 
      {
          System.out.println("Enter Name of client number " + (i+1));
          clientNames[i] = s.nextLine();
          
          System.out.println("How much would you like to invest? (100-10000)");
          amountInvested[i] = Integer.parseInt(s.nextLine());
          
          System.out.println("What is the interest rate?");
          totalRate[i] = Integer.parseInt(s.nextLine());
          
          System.out.println("How long will your investment gain interest? ");
          years[i] = Integer.parseInt(s.nextLine());
          
          
      }
    
    // Declare for loop for output here
      for(int j = 0; j < totalClients; j++) 
      {
          System.out.print(clientNames[j]);
          
          search = table [years[j]] [totalRate[j]];
          double finalBalance = amountInvested[j] * search;
          System.out.printf("     Compound value: $%.2f", finalBalance);
          
          double amountGained = finalBalance - amountInvested[j];
          System.out.printf("       Interest: $%.2f", amountGained);
          
          System.out.println("");
      }
      


 } // end main
} // end class
```

Im 99% positive it is in the last for loop. My best guess at the moment is that it is something with this line...

```
search = table [years[j]] [totalRate[j]];
```

Edit: I completley missed this in my  review, here is the error code i am getting.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 8 out of bounds for length 6
    at Lab04_Part_1.main(Lab04_Part_1.java:51)
```

Comment: Try printing out `years[j]` and `totalRate[j]` If either is >= to either of the table dimensions you have a problem.

Comment: please post the (first few lines of the) exception's stack trace

Answer (score 0):

The problem indeed lies in `search = table [years[j]] [totalRate[j]];`

What are their values? If I enter 20 years into the `years` table, then the program tries to get the value from `table[20]`. As you can see, `years[j]` and `totalRate[j]` are not indexes.

A good way to find out these problems is to use a debugger or to print different variables to console often.

I'm not actually quite sure what you want to do with `table`, so sadly I can't really help with that